# SQL Convert DATETIME to VARCHAR back to DATETIME and keep formatting

Tags: sql, date, datetime, casting

The title is more complicated than the actual problem is.

I have a DATE that needs to be formatted differently (dd/mm/yyyy) so it can be inserted into a  FoxPro database.

This works: 
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),1)

but I need to be able to CAST it back as a DATETIME and keep its changed format.

```
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),1),1) just resets the format.
```

Comment: Try `CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103)`, this should give you date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) has all date conversion info.

Comment: It returns as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: What you see is not the format of the date, only the default text representation of whatever you use to look at the date. A date is of type date, irrespective of its textual represenation.